# How to use secrets in all repositories of a user github account?

Tags: github-actions

In an "organization" github account, I can set some global secrets `PYPI_USERNAME` and `PYPI_PASSWORD`, make them "Available to public repositories", then use them in my `ci.yml` like this:

```
twine upload dist/$PROJECT_NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz -u ${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }} --non-interactive  --skip-existing --disable-progress-bar
```

But in my "user" github account, I can't find any such organization-wide secrets, so I find myself having to enter my secrets for every individual repository, which is a crime against humanity('s time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Github documentation for [Managing encrypted secrets for your repository and organization](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-repository-and-organization-for-codespaces) states that:

> Secrets are encrypted environment variables that you create in an organization or repository.

> Organization-level secrets let you share secrets between multiple
> repositories, which reduces the need to create duplicate secrets. You
> can use access policies to control which repositories can use
> organization secrets.

Therefore, at the moment, only Organization-level secrets let you share secrets between multiple repositories. You will have to create duplicated secrets on your "user account" repositories.

*Note that you can also [create your own organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations), if that makes sense, to resolve your issue.*